# How to add wpf component to win app in .NET 6

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, .net-core, .net-6.0

I create a project `Win App` with `.Net 6`.

I wanna add `wpf` Component to my project but I don't find the `ElementHost` control in `toolbox`.

Has this control been removed?

if yes, how to add `wpf` control to `win` app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like .NET 6 Winform designer doesn't support ElementHost.

[my version is Visual Studio 2022 17.1.1]
[image]

try add ElementHost manually

```
        private System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost elementHost;

        private void InitElementHost()
        {
            this.SuspendLayout();
            this.elementHost.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(236, 156); //location
            this.elementHost.Name = "elementHost1";
            this.elementHost.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 100);
            this.elementHost.TabIndex = 0;
            this.elementHost.Text = "elementHost1";
            this.elementHost.Child = null; //wpf control
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
        }
```

[image]

Comment: sorry ,i forget.you shout add <UseWPF>true<UseWPF> in your .csproj file(.Net Core).

Comment: I have re-edited the reply, you can see the picture above.This is for .Net Core, if it is .Net FrameWork, the designer supports ElementHost

Comment: .NET 6 is .NET *Core* 6. The last version of .NET Framework was 4.8

Comment: I'm inaccurate in my description, my test program was created with .NET 6